# calculating beta for elgamal elliptic curves

Tags: elliptic-curves, elgamal-encryption

Suppose we use elgamal elliptic curves for secure communication. Bob selects a prime $p$, an elliptic curve $E$, a point $\alpha$ on $E \pmod p$, and a secret integer $f$. Suppose that Bob has selected $p =8115633240307$; $E: y^2 = x^3 + 45x + 1$; $\alpha = (1728910711, 274151521448)$, $f=7$;
How would we calculate $\beta = [f]\alpha = [7](1728910711, 274151521448)$?.

Comment: $\alpha+\alpha+\alpha+\alpha+\alpha+\alpha+\alpha$

Comment: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3907/how-does-one-calculate-the-scalar-multiplication-on-elliptic-curves might help too.

Comment: @mikeazo Ya i looked at that and i couldnt relate. By
α+α+α+α+α+α+α , how would addition of the points go?

Comment: @BobbDizzles You need to look up the point addition and doubling formulas for your curve form.

Comment: @CodesInChaos you mean like this?: http://www.voltage.com/blog/math-2/adding-points-on-an-elliptic-curve/

Comment: I'd use an existing ECC library which offers a scalar multiplication function. But if you implement it yourself you can look at the [Explicit-Formulas Database](http://www.hyperelliptic.org/EFD) which as addition/doubling formulas for many curve forms.

Comment: The equations are in the answers I linked to. What exactly don't you understand.

Comment: I'm going to close this for now. Please update to address exactly what you don't understand from the question I linked to above. Then we can reopen (just flag the question).