# Using Montgomery ladder to calculate the coordinates

Tags: elliptic-curves

In one of my assignments I need to solve the problem below:

> For a Montgomery curve $3y^2 = x^3+x^2+x$ over ${\mathbb{F}}_{11}$ and point $P = (9,8)$, compute the $x$ coordinate of $3P$ using the Montgomery ladder.

I just need a hint to get an idea and not the whole answer. if anyone with some useful links would also be appreciable. As I tried to search google for this but was not able to get any idea.

---

Is it that I need to find it as $3P = 2P + P $ because I found one question about scalar multiplication [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3907/how-does-one-calculate-the-scalar-multiplication-on-elliptic-curves). but then I think it is not the correct way to use the Montgomery ladder.

Comment: Do you know what the Montgomery ladder algorithm is?

Comment: Yes I have read about it and I know that we double when we have bit 1 and we add if bit 0. But I am not able to apply here. Or otherwise I haven't that much knowledge about it.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_point_multiplication#Montgomery_ladder

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Montgomery Curve](https://wstein.org/edu/Fall2001/124/misc/montgomery.pdf) is introduced by Peter L. Montgomery for speeding up the Pollard and Elliptic Curve Methods of integer factorization. Montgomery Curves are in the form $By^2=x^3+Ax^2+x$ and it is also represented as $M_{A,B}$.

**Addition and Doubling Formulas of Montgomery Curves**

Given Montgomery Curve $By^2=x^3+Ax^2+x$ and the point $P_1 = (x_1,x_1)$ and $P_2 = (x_2,x_2)$ than the addition and doubling, $P_3 = (x_3,x_3) = P_1+P_2$ as follows

- **Addition formula** in Affine Coordinates: $(P1 \neq \pm P2)$

\begin{align}
\alpha & = (y_2 − y_1)/(x_2 − x_1)\\
x_3 & = B \alpha^2 − A − x_1 − x_2\\
y_3 & = \alpha (x_1 − x_3) − y_1
\end{align}

- **Doubling formula** in Affine Coordinates: $(P1 = P2)$

\begin{align}
\alpha & =  (3x_1^2 + 2 A x_1 + 1)/(2 B y_1)\\
x_3 & = B\alpha^2 − A − 2x_1\\
y_3 & = \alpha (x_1 − x_3) − y_1
\end{align}

As usual, these are [calculated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montgomery_curve#Addition) from the geometrical meaning of addition.

**Montgomery Ladder**

The [Montgomery Ladder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_point_multiplication#Montgomery_ladder) is an algorithm to calculate $[x]P$ for a given scalar $x$ and a point $P$.

Represent $x$ in binary $x= x_0 + 2x_1 + 2^2x_2 + \cdots + 2^mx_m $ and let $m= \lfloor \log_2 x \rfloor$.

```
  R0 = 0
  R1 = P
  for i from m downto 0 do
     if xi = 0 then
        R1 = point_add(R0, R1)
        R0 = point_double(R0)
     else
        R0 = point_add(R0, R1)
        R1 = point_double(R1)
  return R0
```

**Calculation**

Now, $x=3 = 1 + 2\cdot 1$, i.e. $x_0=1$ and $x_1 =1$

$m= \lfloor \log_2 3 \rfloor = 1$. Therefore, we visit the loop twice.

since $x_i =1$ we will be always in the else case, or simply we run the below.

```
  1. R0 = 0
  2. R1 = P
  3. R0 = point_add(R0, R1)
  4. R1 = point_double(R1)
  5. R0 = point_add(R0, R1)
  6. R1 = point_double(R1)
  7. return R0
```

1. $R_0 = \mathcal{O}$
2. $R_1 = P$
3. $R_0 = \mathcal{O} + P = P$
4. $R_1 = P + P = [2]P$
5. $R_0 = [2]P+P = [3]P$
6. $R_1 = [2]P+[2]P = [4]P$
7. return $R_0 = [3]P$

The given [Montgomery Curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montgomery_curve) $3y^2=x^3+x^2+x$ than it is $M_{1,3}$ so $A=1,B=3$ and $P=(9,8)$

$[2]P = (1,10)$ by the below simple sage math point doubling.

```
k.<a> = GF(11, modulus="primitive")
k.modulus()
A = k(1)
B = k(3)
x1 = k(9)
y1 = k(8)
alpha  =  (3*x1^2 + 2 *A * x1 + 1)/(2 * B * y1)
x3 = B * alpha^2 - A - 2 * x1
y3 = alpha *(x1 - x3) - y1
print x3
print y3
```

$[3]P = [2]P+P = (5,2)$ by the below simple sage math point addtion.

```
k.<a> = GF(11)
A = k(1)
B = k(3)
x1 = k(9)
y1 = k(8)
x2 = k(1)
y2 = k(10)
alpha = (y2 - y1)/(x2 - x1)
x3  = B * alpha^2 - A - x1 - x2
y3  = alpha * (x1 - x3) - y1
print x3
print y3
```

---

**Notes :**

- One might say that we don't need step 6 since we are not returning it. Keep in mind that that is a need for protection from side-channel attacks.
- This ladder algorithm from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_point_multiplication#Montgomery_ladder) and it is not an optimal one. See [The Montgomery Powering Ladder](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F3-540-36400-5_22.pdf) for a better version.
- There is also a full coverage chapter "[Montgomery curves and the Montgomery ladder](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/293.pdf)" by Bernstein and Lange to further read.