# Need help understanding SPAKE2 setup values

Tags: elliptic-curves, diffie-hellman, elliptic-curve-generation, pake

I am trying to write a simulation of the SPAKE2 protocol in python (just so I can get a better understanding of the protocol altogether). I am reading through the ietf draft here: [Datatracker](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-irtf-cfrg-spake2/?include_text=1).

There's a lot about cryptography I do not understand though and I am having trouble figuring out how to generate some of the values mentioned in the setup. Here is the excerpt I am talking about:

> Let G be a group in which the computational Diffie-Hellman (CDH)
>   problem is hard. Suppose G has order p*h where p is a large prime; h
>   will be called the cofactor. Let I be the unit element in G, e.g., the
>   point at infinity if G is an elliptic curve group. We denote the
>   operations in the group additively. We assume there is a
>   representation of elements of G as byte strings: common choices would
>   be SEC1 compressed [SEC1] for elliptic curve groups or big endian
>   integers of a fixed (pergroup) length for prime field DH. We fix two
>   elements M and N in the prime-order subgroup of G as defined in the
>   table in this document for common groups, as well as a generator P of
>   the (large) prime-order subgroup of G. P is specified in the document
>   defining the group, and so we do not repeat it here.

More specifically, I don't know how to generate G, p, h, M, N, or P and I don't have the mathematical understanding to know exactly what those values are supposed to be. I would really appreciate any help or guidance.

Comment: You don't need generate all of them. Choose an elliptic curve like [Curve25519](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7748#section-4.1), [sepk256k1](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Secp256k1), etc. then the parameters $G,p,h$ and $P$ are already determined.

Comment: Or just read the draft - it gives all the parameters...

Comment: G (base point), p (field size) and h (cofactor) are given by the group you choose. M and N could be any distinct pair of group elements for which the DL is not known. The draft provides such a pair that you may want to use for interoperability purposes.

Comment: @kelalaka I looked at the Curve25519 link you posted. According to Frank Denis _G_ is called the base point. I see two values designated as the base point on the Curve25519 paper, _u_ and _v_. Which is the value I should use? Also, although I see P mentioned, I cannot find wear it is explicitly given a value.

Comment: @kansas_bulldog382 in Elliptic Curve if affine coordinates are used then every point is represented by a pair $(u,v)$

Comment: @kelalaka Ok, that makes much more sense now. Thank you for your helps so far. I looks like P is also a point defined by two coordinates, but the SPAKE2 protocol calls for P to be multiplied or added to some numbers. Do you know how these operations are carried out since P is actually two numbers?

Comment: @kansas_bulldog382 that is called scalar multiplication with an [example](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/75879/18298)..

Comment: Also, if you are using Curve25519, most existing libraries may "clamp" the scalar (clear the 3 low bits, set the high bit), which can give you trouble when implementing SPAKE2. Make sure that this doesn't happen (for example in libsodium by using `scalarmult_ed25519_base_noclamp()` and `scalarmult_ed25519_noclamp()` - See https://github.com/jedisct1/spake2-ee for an example implementation (although that one is an augmented version, and has a different way to choose M and N).